# Errors loading jQuery in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I know this sort of question has been asked on here but I cannot find an answer related to my issue so sorry for asking again. I am currently testing a new site in IE8 and I am just getting a list or errors about jQuery being undefined (in all js files).

I load them all in the footer of the page and all are stored locally rather then linking to an external source and I get no errors in Chrome, Firefox or Safari.

I must mention I am using HTML5 and CSS3 but this shouldn't be causing problems with loading the jquery.

In my footer:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/response.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.uploadifive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/elevateZoom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

The first error I get in IE8 is 'Object doesn't support this method or property' in jquery.min.js line 1 (obviously it is all on line 1) and that is followed by 'jQuery is undefined' in jquery-ui.js. And so on and so forth.

I have validated the html and all is fine.

Comment: Which jquery version?

Comment: looks like your jquery.js file is corrupted... can you download it again and check

Comment: Thank you @ArunPJohny - I have just downloaded again (v1.10.2) and the errors have gone :)

Answer (score 3):

looks like your jquery.js file is corrupted... can you download it again